# "Bad format "TXT"; must be pem or der" while extracting modulus from the public key

Tags: encryption, openssl, public-key

I ran this command on ubuntu.

```
$  openssl asn1parse -inform TXT -i -in public.pem -strparse 18
```

But got the error below.

```
asn1parse: Bad format "TXT"; must be pem or der
asn1parse: Invalid format "TXT" for -inform
asn1parse: Use -help for summary.
```

I expect to get something like the below.

```
0:d=0  hl=3 l= 137 cons: SEQUENCE
3:d=1  hl=3 l= 129 prim:  INTEGER           :B793F2F926170FAD768F8B1A5769A2243B4CDCAC4780194F59B39E1A2ABC3BB8EA42DB495D17BEC7F7072A11ED4FA510E75A7886A5DB6F71B7AFCA0090CA079889D18AF0669829ED29A8E21D0C09BD19CAAF2FE2CC8121BFC5687AC6698E3022F468A481426486CAD263BE1A119491E034A6E1AB78F19C066D4145A50F9ECFF7
135:d=1  hl=2 l=   3 prim:  INTEGER           :010001
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is not programming or development thus offtopic, but there is no `-inform TXT`. If your file actually is in PEM format, as the name suggests, you don't need to specify any `-inform` because PEM is the default. Unlike all other `openssl` commands, `asn1parse` ignores the PEM header and trailer lines, so 'PEM' will actually process any file that is base64-of-ASN1. However, no one today should be using a 1024-bit RSA key, and for the keys actually used today 18 is not the correct offset. Are you following obsolete instructions, or more likely a website that is a copy of something obsolete?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sorry. But I did what you said and ran `openssl asn1parse -i -in public_utf8.pem -strparse 18` but I got the error `18' is out of range`. And where should I post this question if not here? Superuser.com?

Comment: Check the contents of the file. Is it actually in PEM format (notice the 'If' in my previous comment)? Is it actually a public key (in PEM format)?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yeah you're right. The file format is wrong. Thank you.